# Flutter - How do you take a screenshot of a widget that is not rendered on the screen?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a widget that is currently outside the screen.

Comment: Hi Gary, add some snippets of what you have already done so you people can help you better :)